# Wifi doesn't work on 17.04

Tags: wireless, 17.04

After updating from 16.10 to 17.04, Wi-FI no longer works. I use the  `APPUSB150NAV2` adapter, which worked fine in 16.10.

I also tested with Ubuntu Gnome; it made no difference.

How can I get my Wi-FI working?

Comment: Check out this https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Answer (score 4):

Open the NetworkManager file with your text editor:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

add lines

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

Save and close file then reboot.

Comment: Yes, this works! I would love to know why.

Comment: @labnut, it is a work around for a bug in network manager in 17.04, there are several right noiw effecting many devices in different ways. This one from what I can tell effects all usb devices and some internal ones like ath9k and ath5k drivers.

Comment: I need to clarify a little more actually to be precise it is a new feature of network manager and it was decided that the issue will not be fixed, that with the devices effected it is up to the driver devs to fix each driver that does not handle this new feature well. so it may be a long time before this issue goes completely away, if ever.